# ASP.Net Core maxUrlLength

Tags: asp.net-core

Is there a way to set a maxUrlLength configuration value in Asp.Net Core?  I see how this is done in web.config in earlier versions of the framework, for example:

[How do I increase the maxUrlLength property in the config in asp.net MVC 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8245843/how-do-i-increase-the-maxurllength-property-in-the-config-in-asp-net-mvc-3)

However, this doesn't seem to work in ASP.Net Core....

Comment: It seems like this parameter didnt make it on 1.0 release. Take a look at this issue: https://github.com/aspnet/KestrelHttpServer/issues/475

Comment: This is a function of your front end server (e.g. IIS or NGinx). ASP.NET Core does not yet have a restriction on this value.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You are correct that maxUrlLength configuration value not available is not available ASP.net core the way it is available in previous version. The clean reason for this is that previous version only support IIS and Windows so it is tightly integrated with that. Now It is supported with other OS and to do that the way they did it reverse proxy with actual server. Like In Windows IIS and Linux NGinx.

1. IIS will communicate with Kestrel.
2. NGIx will comminicate with Kestrel.

Now any request filtering or url setting we have to do is at IIS or NGinx level.

If you are working in Windows you will find "Request Filtering" feature and for that you have to add Web.config file. ( I have not tested NGInx)

You have to do something like this.

```
<system.webServer>
    <!--   Here you have other settings related to handlers.-->
   <security>
      <requestFiltering>
         <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="3000000" maxUrl="10241" maxQueryString="20481" />
      </requestFiltering>
   </security>
 </system.webServer>
```

Comment: This answer is in the correct ballpark, and I changed various pieces of configuration along the lines described here, but the FINAL change that got things working was with an update to my registry, described here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15004232/wcf-get-url-length-limit-issue-bad-request-invalid-url

Note I'm using IIS Express, and this also required a reboot of my machine for the registry setting to take effect.

Comment: The answer worked for me in .NET6 as per https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webServer/security/requestFiltering/requestLimits/

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this can help

KestrelServerLimits.MaxRequestLineSize Property

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.server.kestrel.core.kestrelserverlimits.maxrequestlinesize?view=aspnetcore-3.1#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Server_Kestrel_Core_KestrelServerLimits_MaxRequestLineSize

Answer (score 0):

I answered a similar question https://stackoverflow.com/a/77903372/2410655.

I have a web application written in .NET 6, and setting `MaxRequestLineSize` didn't work for me:

```cs
public class Program
{
    public static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

        builder.WebHost.ConfigureKestrel(options =>
        {
            options.Limits.MaxRequestLineSize = 302768;
        });
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

And since it's an ASP.NET Core web app, it doesn't have a web.config you can play with in the project. Of course, you can change it manually on the server each time you deploy but...

The only thing that worked for me is web.config transformation:

1. Add a web.release.config in your web project
2. Transform necessary XML nodes

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration
  xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
  <system.web xdt:Transform="InsertIfMissing">
    <httpRuntime maxQueryStringLength="32768" maxUrlLength="65536" xdt:Transform="InsertIfMissing"/>
  </system.web>
  <location>
    <system.webServer>
      <security xdt:Transform="InsertIfMissing">
        <requestFiltering xdt:Transform="InsertIfMissing">
          <requestLimits maxQueryString="32768" xdt:Transform="InsertIfMissing" />
        </requestFiltering>
      </security>
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
```