# Increase max url length in asp.net core

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have an asp.net core web api, that enables tts requests. You basically request `http://server.url/Whatever you want it to say.mp3` to get an mp3 with the text spoken in tts.

But the problem is, that it will return a `400 - The request URL is invalid` if I pass it a long string. It seems like the server is hitting some sort of max URL length limitation. I can find information on how to fix this is the "classic" asp.net web.config, but not how to fix this in asp.net core.

What is the correct way of increasing the maximum URL length in asp.net core?

**Update:**

The exact url is for instance:

http://localhost:5000/api/mp3/nl-NL/male/1/Wikipedia%20is%20een%20online%20encyclopedie%20die%20tracht%20inhoud%20te%20bieden%20die%20vrij%20herbruikbaar,%20objectief%20en%20verifieerbaar%20is.%20Het%20project%20is%20gebouwd%20op%20vijf%20zuilen.%20De%20Nederlandstalige%20versie%20startte%20op%2019%20juni%202001%20en%20is,%20gemeten%20naar%20het%20aantal%20artikelen,%20met%20bijna%201,9%20miljoen%20artikelen%20de%20op%20vier%20na%20grootste%20taalversie.mp3

It is URL-encoded. I'll try to figure out what the exact maximum is.

I cannot use a POST, as the tool that is going to make use of this only supports urls for mp3 files (hence the .mp3 extension used in my controller).

**Update 2**

The longest request it accepts has 397 characters, which does not seem very logical. If I add one more, it will return a code 400.

**Update 3**

It turns out to only have this issue when deployed on the server (using IIS), when run locally, it supports way longer strings (I haven't seen it return a code 400 yet). I'll have to look into IIS to see where it goes wrong.

Comment: What is the exact URL you're using?

Comment: You could use POST instead of GET.

Comment: how large (mancy characters) exactly when it crashes? did you try url_encoding your url (spaces => `%20` or `+`)?

Answer (score 17):

As it turns out, I needed two things to fix this:

**Change web.config**

I needed to add the following to the web.config to instruct IIS to allow longer URLs:

```xml
<system.webServer>
    <security>
        <requestFiltering allowDoubleEscaping="false">
            <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="30000000" maxUrl="40960" maxQueryString="20480" />
        </requestFiltering>
    </security>
</system.webServer>
```

**Edit registry**

After this, IIS will still throw a code 400, because the UrlSegment length is too long. Sadly, the only way to change this is by some minor registry hacking.

Navigate to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\HTTP\Parameters` and find the key UrlSegmentMaxLength. If it is not there, create one with a value type of REG_DWORD. I used 1000 HEX (4096 DEC) as the value. The default value is 260 if the key is not there yet.

Before the change was effective, I needed to reboot the server though.

Comment: I was struggling with this until I saw your last comment: "I needed to reboot the server though." I'm baffled that restarting IIS wasn't enough.

Comment: Just added the web.config section and worked for me in .net core 3.1

Answer (score 4):

The accepted solution did not work for me. I am running asp.net core 2.0 on iis express locally. What worked is configuring Kestrel "directly" in startup.cs. I did not need to change the registry or reboot the machine.

```
 var host = new WebHostBuilder()
          .UseKestrel(options => {
              options.Limits.MaxRequestBufferSize = 302768;
              options.Limits.MaxRequestLineSize = 302768;
          })
```

I added to my web.config the following (although i am not sure it made the difference.)

```
<requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="1073741824" maxUrl="20480" maxQueryString="20480" />
```

This is where i found it: https://titanwolf.org/Network/Articles/Article?AID=2fa1aad6-6b3d-479e-9770-a0850497d270

Comment: Where can I find web.config file in the asp.net core solution ?

Comment: @shivu By default it will not exist in a new .Net Core/5/6/7+ app. It is not included in the app template. However, _some_ hosting environments, such as IIS, require at least a minimal `web.confg` file. You can add one manually. The file content format is the same as the old-style asp.net `web.config` files. For .Net Core apps the file can be much smaller; normally it used only by IIS, not the app itself.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error on my web application written in .NET 6 too:

> HTTP Error 404.15 - Not Found
> The request filtering module is configured to deny a request where the query string is too long.

@mjepson's solution won't work, because ASP.NET Core web applications now don't have a web.config you can work on.

I tried the solution suggested by @armyllc and that didn't work for me:

```cs
public class Program
{
    public static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

        builder.WebHost.ConfigureKestrel(options =>
        {
            options.Limits.MaxRequestLineSize = 302768;
        });
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

The only thing that worked for me is **web.config transformation**:

1. Add a `web.release.config` in your web project
2. Transform necessary XML nodes

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration
  xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
  <system.web xdt:Transform="InsertIfMissing">
    <httpRuntime maxQueryStringLength="32768" maxUrlLength="65536" xdt:Transform="InsertIfMissing"/>
  </system.web>
  <location>
    <system.webServer>
      <security xdt:Transform="InsertIfMissing">
        <requestFiltering xdt:Transform="InsertIfMissing">
          <requestLimits maxQueryString="32768" xdt:Transform="InsertIfMissing" />
        </requestFiltering>
      </security>
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
```