# Error 404 in long urls Angular 4

Tags: angular, iis-8, angular-routing, angular-router

Hi I have an application in Angular 4 with backend in Asp net Core Web API.
I'm having a problem when calling a very long url.

URL:
http://www.condominio-mais.com/usuario/resetar/4995ffba-6e78-486e-8653-0fb8f4e6996e/CfDJ8KvZVIfag49BieUUcQkCHC0WR%2FQNYNjUtosCAOJ6V5VTJHn0phbIUB4zWt2wWX3rKBK3iwrktVIzeuuZ5bYOQYFMGSN2cFTkKx%2B7AcN0Uw7KcpPwkhU2fGDAMUssZMxwqNnoEPscVdZIQJlQ4NvbAyHSJk4I9g1wjZoTumSiT5VDDkebFvjild8RVoFtXYcsObpvpfgmxT3Cdld5h%2Fot3L5h3qkYSbfbg%2BxcE1VTxJb5saXQYWtnnDBJb4aBwH5zZg%3D%3D

this url has two ID and TOKEN parameters. If I decrease the token it works perfectly, but if I use it as above I get error 404.

The application is hosted on Azure. I already did the configuration with web.config, it worked for the screen refresh cases, but for the long urls it does not work.

Do you have any idea what it is?

**The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.**

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
CfDJ8KvZVIfag49BieUUcQkCHC0WR%2FQNYNjUtosCAOJ6V5VTJHn0phbIUB4zWt2wWX3rKBK3iwrktVIzeuuZ5bYOQYFMGSN2cFTkKx%2B7AcN0Uw7KcpPwkhU2fGDAMUssZMxwqNnoEPscVdZIQJlQ4NvbAyHSJk4I9g1wjZoTumSiT5VDDkebFvjild8RVoFtXYcsObpvpfgmxT3Cdld5h%2Fot3L5h3qkYSbfbg%2BxcE1VTxJb5saXQYWtnnDBJb4aBwH5zZg%3D%3D

Comment: Have you seen this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42243211/increase-max-url-length-in-asp-net-core

Comment: Hi DeborahK! i made the settings you indicated, worked partially. thank you so much!

I noticed that the error happens when the URL is encoded. When I remove the special characters the url works.