# HTTP Error 414 when routing to login page

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I am developing an application using ASP.NET core 6 MVC. Razor pages Utilizing  the Entity Framework and Identity as well. The problem I am getting and cant seem to debug is:

1. whenever I used the scaffold _LoginPartial i receive this error 414
   when trying to redirect to the login page turns out that may have
   not been the problem. So I remove the _loginpartial recreated the
   branch and no problems until...
2. I was trying to test my role base policy authentication and could not successfully
   login into my second user due to my seeded
   user not logging out. now whenever i would restart the application
   it would load my index page and i could then click log in button and
   login, but in the midst of testing my role base policy
   authentication my user stayed logged in. So I had the bright idea to
   delete the cookies from the browser and then got the same error
   again 414. I dont know what to do to fix this problem.

the project could be found on my github because i really don't know which page to share https://github.com/Timmysworld/TheGospelMission2/tree/RoleManagement4/TheGospelMission

```
**Program.cs**
--------------

using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using TheGospelMission.Data;
using TheGospelMission.Areas.Identity.Data;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using TheGospelMission.Services;
using TheGospelMission.Permission;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);


//DI for DbContext
builder.Services.AddDbContext<GospelMissionDbContext>(options =>
{
    options.UseMySql(
        builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DbConnection"),
        ServerVersion.AutoDetect(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DbConnection"))
    );

    options.EnableSensitiveDataLogging(); // Enable query logging
});


builder.Services.Configure<IdentityOptions>(options =>
{
    // Default User settings.
    options.User.AllowedUserNameCharacters =
            "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789-._@+";
    options.User.RequireUniqueEmail = false;

});

builder.Services.Configure<IdentityOptions>(options =>
    {
        // Default Password settings.
        options.Password.RequireDigit = true;
        options.Password.RequireLowercase = true;
        options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = true;
        options.Password.RequireUppercase = true;
        options.Password.RequiredLength = 6;
        options.Password.RequiredUniqueChars = 1;
    });

builder.Services.AddDefaultIdentity<TheGospelMissionUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = false)
    .AddDefaultTokenProviders()
    .AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<GospelMissionDbContext>();

// Add session services
builder.Services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();
builder.Services.AddSession(options =>
{
    options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30); // Adjust as needed
});
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IAuthorizationPolicyProvider, PermissionPolicyProvider>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IAuthorizationHandler, PermissionAuthorizationHandler>();

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();
builder.Services.AddScoped<GospelMissionDbContext>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<GroupService>(); // Use the appropriate scope (e.g., Scoped, Transient, or Singleton) as per your application's requirements
builder.Services.AddScoped<MembersService>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<ChurchesService>();

builder.Services.AddRazorPages();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    // The default HSTS refresh is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseSession(); // Add this before app.UseRouting()
app.UseRouting();
app.UseAuthentication();;

app.UseAuthorization();
app.MapRazorPages();

// Exception Handling Middleware
app.Use(async (context, next) =>
{
    await next.Invoke();
    try
    {
        await next.Invoke();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
       // Log the exception (you can use a logging library like Serilog or NLog)
       // You can customize the error response here
        context.Response.StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError;
        await context.Response.WriteAsync("An error occurred. Please try again later.");
    }
});

app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
        name: "default",
        pattern: "/");


    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
        name: "api",
        pattern: "api/v1/{controller}/{action}",
        constraints: new { action = "(create|dashboard|index|update)" }
        );
    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
            name: "apiWithID",
            pattern: "api/v1/{controller}/{action}/{id:length(24)}",
            constraints: new { action = "(view|edit|deleteRole|deleteUser|delete)" }
        );
});

using (var scope = app.Services.CreateScope())
{
    var roleManager =
        scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<RoleManager<IdentityRole>>();

    var roles = new[] { "Super Admin","Group Leader" };
    foreach (var role in roles)
    {
        if (!await roleManager.RoleExistsAsync(role))
            await roleManager.CreateAsync(new IdentityRole(role));
    }
}

using (var scope = app.Services.CreateScope())
{
    var userManager =
        scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<UserManager<TheGospelMissionUser>>();


    string username = "TimmyTurner";
    string email = "superadmin@admin.com";
    string password = "Password1!";
    int churchId = 1;


    if (await userManager.FindByEmailAsync(email) == null)
    {
        var user = new TheGospelMissionUser();
        user.UserName = username;
        user.Email = email;
        user.ChurchId = churchId;

        await userManager.CreateAsync(user,password);
        await userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user, "Super Admin");

    }

}

app.Run();
```

not sure if showing my login.cshtml.cs page will help but here it is just in case

```
// The .NET Foundation licenses this file to you under the MIT license.
#nullable disable

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI.Services;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using TheGospelMission.Areas.Identity.Data;

namespace TheGospelMission.Areas.Identity.Pages.Account
{
    public class LoginModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly SignInManager<TheGospelMissionUser> _signInManager;
        private readonly ILogger<LoginModel> _logger;

        public LoginModel(SignInManager<TheGospelMissionUser> signInManager, ILogger<LoginModel> logger)
        {
            _signInManager = signInManager;
            _logger = logger;
        }

        /// <summary>
        ///     This API supports the ASP.NET Core Identity default UI infrastructure and is not intended to be used
        ///     directly from your code. This API may change or be removed in future releases.
        /// </summary>
        [BindProperty]
        public InputModel Input { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        ///     This API supports the ASP.NET Core Identity default UI infrastructure and is not intended to be used
        ///     directly from your code. This API may change or be removed in future releases.
        /// </summary>
        public IList<AuthenticationScheme> ExternalLogins { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        ///     This API supports the ASP.NET Core Identity default UI infrastructure and is not intended to be used
        ///     directly from your code. This API may change or be removed in future releases.
        /// </summary>
        public string ReturnUrl { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        ///     This API supports the ASP.NET Core Identity default UI infrastructure and is not intended to be used
        ///     directly from your code. This API may change or be removed in future releases.
        /// </summary>
        [TempData]
        public string ErrorMessage { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        ///     This API supports the ASP.NET Core Identity default UI infrastructure and is not intended to be used
        ///     directly from your code. This API may change or be removed in future releases.
        /// </summary>
        public class InputModel
        {
            /// <summary>
            ///     This API supports the ASP.NET Core Identity default UI infrastructure and is not intended to be used
            ///     directly from your code. This API may change or be removed in future releases.
            /// </summary>
            [Required]
            public string Username { get; set; }

            /// <summary>
            ///     This API supports the ASP.NET Core Identity default UI infrastructure and is not intended to be used
            ///     directly from your code. This API may change or be removed in future releases.
            /// </summary>
            [Required]
            [DataType(DataType.Password)]
            public string Password { get; set; }

            /// <summary>
            ///     This API supports the ASP.NET Core Identity default UI infrastructure and is not intended to be used
            ///     directly from your code. This API may change or be removed in future releases.
            /// </summary>
            [Display(Name = "Remember me?")]
            public bool RememberMe { get; set; }
        }

        public async Task OnGetAsync(string returnUrl = null)
        {
            
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ErrorMessage))
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, ErrorMessage);
            }

            returnUrl ??= Url.Content("~/");

            // Clear the existing external cookie to ensure a clean login process
            await HttpContext.SignOutAsync(IdentityConstants.ExternalScheme);

            ExternalLogins = (await _signInManager.GetExternalAuthenticationSchemesAsync()).ToList();

            ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
        }

        public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(string returnUrl = null)
        {
            returnUrl ??= Url.Action("dashboard", "Home");

            ExternalLogins = (await _signInManager.GetExternalAuthenticationSchemesAsync()).ToList();

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                // This doesn't count login failures towards account lockout
                // To enable password failures to trigger account lockout, set lockoutOnFailure: true
                var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(Input.Username, Input.Password, Input.RememberMe, lockoutOnFailure: false);
                //if(result.Succeeded)
                //{
                //    var roles = await _signInManager.UserManager.GetRolesAsync(User);
                //}
                if (result.Succeeded)
                {
                    _logger.LogInformation("User logged in.");
                    return LocalRedirect(returnUrl);
                }
                if (result.RequiresTwoFactor)
                {
                    return RedirectToPage("./LoginWith2fa", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl, RememberMe = Input.RememberMe });
                }
                if (result.IsLockedOut)
                {
                    _logger.LogWarning("User account locked out.");
                    return RedirectToPage("./Lockout");
                }
                else
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Invalid login attempt.");
                    return Page();
                }
            }

            // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
            return Page();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [414 (Request-URI Too Long)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54087816/414-request-uri-too-long)

Comment: i'm sure I understand fully the link you provided.

Comment: seems to suggest that you're using a URL that's too long.  I'd check the value of "returnUrl".  (set a breakpoint at those redirects to check...)

Comment: None of the break points are hitting

Comment: do you see a really long URL at the top of the browser?  If so, find out what's causing that.  Usually a GET when a POST should be used...

Comment: the only break point that hits is one block of code ``` public Task<AuthorizationPolicy> GetFallbackPolicyAsync()
        {
            return FallbackPolicyProvider.GetDefaultPolicyAsync();
        }```

Comment: yea its this https://localhost:7133/Account/login?ReturnUrl=%2FAccount%2Flogin%3FReturnUrl%3D%252FAccount%252Flogin%253FReturnUrl%253D%25252FAccount%25252Flogin%25253FReturnUrl%25253D%2525252FAccount%2525252Flogin%2525253FReturnUrl%2525253D%252525252FAccount%252525252Flogin%252525253FReturnUrl%252525253D%25252525252FAccount%25252525252Flogin% and then it repeats

Comment: Also im using the default identity set up and they have both onGetAsync and OnPostAsync.

Comment: looks like you've got some looping happening...(maybe redirecting over and over until the url gets that long?) take away all the return url stuff.  Don't try to retain the current page.  Instead just redirect to a single home page.  Then figure out what's wrong with the code that's trying to redirect back to original landed page.

Comment: Idk how to fix this i tried changing the route on the onGetAsync like you suggested and still the same thing i even reject my custom middleware

Comment: Please check the below answer and tell me if it works for you ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fix the issue by adding `[AllowAnonymous]` in `LoginModel`. Then it will works well.

[image]

[image]

Comment: after adding that im getting this error : Exception has occurred: CLR/System.InvalidOperationException
Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidOperationException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll: 'Headers are read-only, response has already started.'

Comment: that could be coming from the "Exception Handling Middleware": await context.Response.WriteAsync  when catching...  If not, check that when you set a cookie it is always the first response... you can't send headers/page, and then set a cookie from server-side.  Must always be set cookie first.  Same would go for deleting cookie.

Comment: Hi @pcalkins, after further checking the issue, I find this line `builder.Services.AddSingleton<IAuthorizationPolicyProvider, PermissionPolicyProvider>();`, if I comment it and it works well. So could you kindly check the code about `PermissionPolicyProvider` , after using it, and the `[AllowAnonymous]` should be needed.

Comment: I wanted to say that a combination of all you guys suggestions have helped and thank you. I needed to add the AllowAnonymous and i did have some redirect issues but was found in my register route. now on to my next but original problem lol but thank you guys again