# I get a 400 bad request - invalid Url when the length of the request exceeds 320+ characters

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, uri

Not sure what could be the reason. Added the following in Web.config also.
maxUrlLength="1024" maxQueryStringLength="1024" requestPathInvalidCharacters="" maxRequestLength="1024" relaxedUrlToFileSystemMapping="true"
I encode the uri parameter and send the request but get a invalid url all the time.
Url: http://localhost:51840/api/xxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxxxxx/n4cEF3OM0LC0q8I6OMe0XdHo8evXnoeyC06A%252fL%252fu0a%252f6e0RQrdxl2%252fPkSKNfh4aEQm78TReX1zIfGDB1bgH%252bGBEI%252fBw6i0DwQ6%252b3dk6yjs1UZqqICQye6QqVX8bJT%252fBK7GE8a22FeXJiPVtEgFRmp4WcHc4pIRHaE6QGK28kiASGFfUC9tDdRZhLfmYJsluGpsseSUOc5Inxlf3fTFNe7sg7gixrLTlwhfJIATZWWsPc%252bfo6BITTFA%253d%253d

If I reduce the url to the following it works fine.
http://localhost:51840/api/xxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxxxxx/n4cEF3OM0LC0q8I6OMe0XdHo8evXnoeyC06A%252fL%252fu0a%252f6e0RQrdxl2%252fPkSKNfh4aEQm78TReX1zIfGDB1bgH%252bGBEI%252fBw6i0DwQ6%252b3dk6yjs1UZqqICQye6QqVX8bJT%252fBK7GE8a22FeXJiPVtEgFRmp4WcHc4pIRHaE6QGK28kiASGFfUC9tDdRZhLfmYJsluGpsseSUOc5Inxlf3fTFNe7sg7gixrLTlwhfJIATZWWsPc%252bfo6BI

When the last 10+ characters it gives me a bad request. Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have a look at the following may need a Registry change as well [url-length-issue] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15004232/wcf-get-url-length-limit-issue-bad-request-invalid-url)

Comment: Thanks for the reply Mark. But can't these registry settings be overridden in the web.config file?

Comment: I believe your issue is that by default the maximum url segment length is 260 and this needs to be increased. This is controlled by the value in registry i believe called UrlSegmentMaxLength increa it to something larger, or work out a way to reduce the size of your url segments. A url segment is the amount of character between the slashes, in your case its  alot !

Comment: is this a restfull api ? ...if yes , its better to go with a http post with content in the body if you having a large content.

Comment: Replaced the url segment into a querystring parameter and it worked fine. Thought this is better compared to editing the registry.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Just documenting my experience:

My issue was the one pointed by @Mark at the question comments:

> "*by default the maximum url segment length is 260*"

He suggested to increase this limit in the registry, but I didn't want this kind of trouble. The suggestion by @Vignesh T worked better:

> "*Replaced the url segment into a querystring parameter and it worked fine*"

In summary, instead of doing:

```
http://path.to.website/very-long-string-goes-here/
```

I just did:

```
http://path.to.website/?key=very-long-string-goes-here
```

Comment: It does, but some people are required to deal with it for whatever reason/requirement, so...

Comment: I owe you a beer

Answer (score 14):

run in powershell

`Set-ItemProperty -Path HKLM:\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\HTTP\Parameters -Name UrlSegmentMaxLength -Value 2000 -Type "Dword"`

then do `net stop http` and `net start http`.

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/amyd/2014/02/06/response-400-bad-request-on-long-url/

Comment: thanks for that, save my day... After many tries with web.config changes (which didn't fix it)

Comment: awesome, thank you. nice clean solution in 30 seconds