# URL too long for OData and ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, odata, iis-express, kestrel

I've set up an OData service using ASP.NET Core Web API with OData ([Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData/)).

My unbound function has one parameter accepting a string that can be very long: `http://localhost:5000/odata/MyFunction(ids='a,b,c,d,e,f')`.

This works fine if the length of `ids` doesn't get too big. However, when passing a too long string, the request fails with `HTTP 400`.

[I've already tried this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18905443/4919526) - unfortunately, it didn't work.

How do I have to configure the app so that long requests are supported both in production ([Kestrel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/kestrel?view=aspnetcore-3.1)) and dev ([IIS Express](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/introduction-to-iis-express/iis-express-overview)) mode?

Comment: How long is "long"?

Comment: Total length of URL: 288 signs are OK, 289 fail

Comment: Can you try using a querystring param instead? See this Q: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40448588

Comment: Yes, this helps somehow: I had to change my parameter types because `DateTimeOffset` doesn't seem to be supported. Furthermore, I couldn't find any information about how to create an OData operation instead of function (this is the difference between `MyFunction(*)` and `MyFunction?*`, as far as I understand). So I can call it as a regular Web API, but OData clients cannot

Answer (score 3):

The problem is not the length of the URL itself. Instead, it is related to OData functions, which lead to a very long URL **segment**. On Windows, this seems to be limited to 260 characters. So in my case, the URL segment `MyFunction(ids='a,b,c,d,e,f')` is simply too long.

I found two different approaches:

1. Change a Windows Registry setting ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7817739/4919526)). I didn't test it, but the comments in the other thread look promising.
2. Use [Parameter Aliases](http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata/v4.01/odata-v4.01-part1-protocol.html#sec_ParameterAliases).

I've chosen the second approach, so now my URL looks like this: `http://localhost:5000/odata/MyFunction(ids=@p1)?@p1='a,b,c,d,e,f'`. The neat thing about this is that I hadn't to change anything in my OData configuration - it just works.

After a bit of testing, I reached the maximum query string length. I solved this by introducing a `web.config` file with the following content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <requestLimits maxUrl="20100" maxQueryString="20000" />
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>
  </system.webServer>
  <system.web>
    <httpRuntime maxUrlLength="20100" maxQueryStringLength="20000" />
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

The downside of the second approach is that Power BI Desktop doesn't seem to support this easily. I was not able to add a parameter alias within the *simple UI* when browsing an OData service. However, when creating a Power BI Parameter with the long query string, I was able to compose the OData URL with the Power BI Parameter als Parameter Alias on my own.

Comment: Another alternative is to not use a batch. Odata supports batching (and you can submit one item as batch) and then suddenly the URL is the batch endpoint and the payload is in the content ;) No URL length limit anymore.

Comment: But how good is the support of BI tools like Power BI and Tableau for batching? I'd expect rather poor 

Comment: It is not. It is a way that is defined in the odata specs as alternative. It is not the responsibility of the specs to support tools that do ignore the specs.

Comment: Sure, I totally agree with you. But on the other hand, writing a spec compliant OData service which cannot be used by our customers is not an option either

Comment: Yeah, So?  Do not get me wrong - I also write odata services. But at the end, whoever writes a consumer has to follow the specs, too. URL length limitations are a fact of life (and yes, you can increase them - but how do you do that on a corporate firewall that your clients may use?). This is a bad scenarios regardless how yo ulook at it