# How to sign-out using the end session endpoint IdentityServer4?

Tags: c#, asp.net, identityserver4

I've tried to logout from my session using *GET* request from IdentityServer4 docs. 
HttpResponseMessage looks like this:

```
HttpResponseMessage res = await client.GetAsync($"connect/endsession?id_token_hint={idTokenHint}&post_logout_redirect_uri={postLogoutRedirectUri}");
```

At first, I have a problem with Uri lenght. When I send request, method catch exception

```
Invalid URI: The Uri scheme is too long.
```

To fix this problem I've tried send parameters into string like this:

```
var parameters = $"?id_token_hint={idTokenHint}&post_logout_redirect_uri={postLogoutRedirectUri}";
HttpResponseMessage res = await client.GetAsync("connect/endsession" + parameters );
```

Also add **MaxRequestLineSize** in Program.cs like this:

```
UseKestrel(options =>
{
  options.Limits.MaxRequestLineSize = 20480;
})
```

Also tried this way: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32457474/9541386 But nothing working for me.

I've tried send this request by Postman. Request was sent

```
http://localhost:5000/connect/endsession?id_token_hint={idTokenHint}&post_logout_redirect_uri={postLogoutRedirectUri}
```

but in FindClientByIdAsync method from IClientStore interface clientId parameter looks like this:
[image]

But in normal case there is **Id**. I can't see what happens before it because it's first entry point.
How can I fix problem with Uri length and wrong parameter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is most likely an invalid character in the query parameters:

```
?id_token_hint={idTokenHint}&post_logout_redirect_uri={postLogoutRedirectUri}
```

In this case I suspect the string postLogoutRedirectUri that contains the character `:`, which is invalid if not escaped: `%3A`.

Encode the uri:

```
var encodedUri = System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode(postLogoutRedirectUri);
```

And use this as parameter:

```
?id_token_hint={idTokenHint}&post_logout_redirect_uri={encodedUri}
```

---

While that may fix the problem, why don't you use the [provided methods to signout](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/topics/signout.html)? E.g.:

```
//using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication;
//using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

// Remove cookie
await HttpContext.SignOutAsync("Cookies");
// Signout oidc
await HttpContext.SignOutAsync("oidc");
```

Comment: @ruard-van-elburg Thanks a lot! Url is valid now. 
But problem with sign-out is still not solved because I use JWT tokens and unfortunately common sign-out methods not working for them as I know

Comment: @d_f Lady calls endsession on backchannel because she use React -> backend -> IdentityServer architecture and configure IdentityServer on my own and calling requests like /connect/token or connect/endpoint it's right way for me as I know :))

Comment: @Melianessa that's not designed to work through backchannel at all: the idea of signout is to clear the auth cookie for Idp + inform all the clients logged in during the current session -- all that actions need access to the browser, and thus have to go through your front. that's the default way. you can implement your own. but in that case you need to start thinking about persisting your idsrv session in some custom place, not a cookie. do you really need that? hard to believe

Comment: @Melianessa when you do not need a session in idsrv at all (only one app, no need of SSO), use resource owner password flow, when logging out, just clear the token you keep locally in the app and don't touch the IdSrv. that should work. but in that case you shouldn't need the idsrv... not clear again

Comment: @d_f for sign-in I send GET request to /connect/token, get access token, create global var for them and send it in all authorize requests in headers. It works for me. In sign-out case I thought I'll do something similar - send GET request to /connect/endsession with parameters, my token will expire or delete or something else and everything will good. But it doesn't work.. may be you know some another way - not with endsession request and SignOutAsync?

Comment: @d_f yes, browser won't be authenticated anymore, but token will exist somewhere and it still valid. If someone has copied the token from the request before, he would be able to perform requests on behalf of the user

Comment: @Melianessa jwt can't be invalidated before it expires -- that's by design. that's why calling endsession endpoint would'n help you. that's about session, cookies and persistent grants, not about jwts someone persists somewhere. what you can do with that -- is setting as short ttl as possible. and use refresh tokens to get new bearer when needed. and delete that refresh token on signout.

Comment: @d_f thanks in advance for help, I'll try go deep into it :)

Comment: where did u get the (id_token_hint) from ?